# Remapping Keys in Insert Mode Completion ( Autocomplete / ^X )

Tags: autocompletion

Using: NeoVim

I would like to remap `j`/`k` in `Insert completion mode`:

- tab starts autocompletion (done, used :help ins-complete example)
- `j`/`k` navigate results like `<C-n>`/`<C-p>`

If I understand correctly the `Insert completion mode` simply shares rebinds with the normal `Insert mode`, so there's no `inoremap` equivalent (i.e. `pnoremap` for comPlete). So is there some way of doing this?

I would prefer not to use a plugin. A best case solution would not break my existing `inoremap jk <esc>` binding, but I would also be interested in solutions that break that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work and still allow your `jk` to function:

```
imap <expr> j pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : 'j'
imap <expr> k pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : 'k'
```

Comment: On my install (`NVIM v0.9.2`) `pumvisible()` returns `v:null` when called. So these keymaps won't work. Is there an alternative to `pumvisible` in newer versions?

Comment: @hmaier that sounds like a bug unless you can point me to intentional docs where they changed it…